# Run commands in terminal in discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord.js

what i want to do is run commands in my console, but idk how to create a listener for the commands in console.

`client.on("message", async message => { //rest of the code`

that but in a version that'll work in console too, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you may be able to use [this](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/) but I really don't know why you would want to do that. Most discord commands need a message object to work and you won't have that in a console.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that could be done using a module called prompt-sync
(https://www.codecademy.com/articles/getting-user-input-in-node-js)

Example :

```
      let guess = prompt('Enter your command : ');   
if (guess === "message") {
        client.channels.cache.get(`644164162968223744`).send(`Hey, this is a message`)    
    }
```